# css transition not working when using it with javascript

Tags: html, css

I know this is a rookie mistake but still can't figure it out.
so, I created a hamburger button using css, I don't think the code is necessary for this but basically when I click on it I wrote a js script that will pop up a navbar

```
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <ul class="nav-links text-center">
    <li><a href="#header" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#search" class="nav-link">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#popular-places" class="nav-link">Popular Places</a></li>

    <li><a href="#gallery" class="nav-link">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is the html code, js is working fine. all I want is to add a transition so when the class `.hamburger-menu` pop up there will be a smooth fade in effect, but nothing works.

```css
.hamburger-menu {
transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

what's wrong with this? I just tried many times but this seems the only right solution yet still not working

when I click on the hamburger button it will add a class named `open-nav` to html and I tried to add transition here too but still nothing

Comment: I think that you need to use `animation` for `open-nav` class if you toggle class not `transition` + also you need to add the menu elements full css, js

Answer (score 0):

How to add user hover transition:

```
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <ul class="nav-links text-center">
    <li><a href="#header" class="nav-link">Home</a>    </li>
    <li><a href="#search" class="nav-link">Search</a>    </li>
    <li><a href="#popular-places" class="nav-    link">Popular Places</a></li>

    <li><a href="#gallery" class="nav-link">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.nav-link:hover {
    width: 300px;
    color: lightblue;
    transition: ease 0.2s;
}
```